# Perl Screen Scrape Data from Table

Tags: regex, perl, screen, scrape

I would like write a Perl script to get the html contents of a webpage and then scrape the contents of a table. The exact page is:

http://djbpmstudio.com/Default.aspx?Page=album&id=1

So far I am able to regex the Artist, Album, and Genre as well as the first entry in the table using the code below:

```
use LWP::Simple;

$url = "http://djbpmstudio.com/Default.aspx?Page=album&id=1";
my $mystring = get($url) or die "Error fetching source page.";
$mystring =~ s/[\r\n]/ /g;      #remove line breaks from HTML
$mystring =~ s/(>)\s+(<)/$1$2/g;    #Remove white space between html tags 
#print $mystring;

if($mystring =~ m{</table><h1>(.*?) - (.*?) - (.*?)</h1>}) {
    #Get Artist name and print
    print "Artist: $1\n";
    print "Album:  $2\n";
    print "Genre:  $3\n\n";

    if($mystring =~ m{</tr><tr class="row-(.*?)"><td>(.*?)</td><td align="right">(.*?)</td></tr>}) {
        #Get Songname and BPM and print
        #print "$1\t";
        print "$2\t";
        print "$3\n";
    }
}
```

In the nest IF, the class alternates between "row-a" and "row-b".

I am not sure how to go down the list and get all of the song names and BPMs for each. I would also like to put the songnames and BPMs into an array for processing later.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [regular expressions to process HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is nearly always a bad idea.

Don't be bad.

Use a module that understands HTML data for processing HTML data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $html = get 'http://djbpmstudio.com/Default.aspx?Page=album&id=1';

my $te = new HTML::TableExtract( headers => ['Track Name', 'BPM'] );
$te->parse($html);
foreach my $ts ($te->table_states) {
   foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
       next unless $row->[0] =~ /\w/;   # skip garbage rows
       printf "%-20s   ==>   %.2f\n", $row->[0], $row->[1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.10/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm) to scrape data from tables, it will make your life much easier.